# how to open a BaseX database from the context in a FLOWR for XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, basex

How do I set the context as a specific database and then reference that database in a FLOWR?

```
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex> basex .\openDB.xq
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex> type .\openDB.xq
let $db := db:open("books")
for $item in $db
return $item/bookstore/book[3]
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex> basex db.xq
Stopped at C:/Users/thufir/Desktop/basex/db.xq, 1/21:
[XPST0003] Expecting ':=', found 's'.
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex> type .\db.xq
declare context items := db:open("books")

for $ctx in .

return $ctx

PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
PS C:\Users\thufir\Desktop\basex>
```

see also:

[how to return the third book from this bookstore using FLOWR in XQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58424946/262852)

I'd like to specify the database like so:

[how to specify a BaseX database from a FLOWR xquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263623/262852)

but explicitly in the context for the XQuery itself.

Comment: Is `declare context items := db:open("books")` simply a typo and you want `declare context item := db:open("books")` instead? At that is how I interpret the error message you get, the syntax is wrong (`items` instead of `item`).

Comment: good golly, let's pretend this never happened (if that's the case).